# Late initializition error for TabController Flutter Getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I need to make tabbar  and it has to dynamic length . I tried to create a basic version. Tabbar is  a "late" variable because of we dont know how many item it has. let's say 5 for this example.  according to my logic when tabbar controller is loaded the _isLoading false should be false. The other page should return a red or black container depending on the value of the _isLoading. if it is true return black Container else return red Container.  But it's not working. OnInıt function runing and flutter throwing this error "Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'tabController' has not been initialized."  What should i do?

My controller class

```
class MyTabbarController extends GetxController
    with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
   late Rx<TabController> tabController;
  Rx<bool> isLoading = true.obs;
  

  loadController() { 
    tabController.value = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
    isLoading.value = false;
  update();
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    print("oninit");
     
    loadController();

    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

and this is where am i using it

```
class _UrunKategorileriState extends State<UrunKategorileri> {
  MyTabbarController tabbarController = Get.put(MyTabbarController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    return Obx(() {
      return tabbarController.isLoading.value
          ? Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: 20,
            )
          : Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 20,
            );
    });
  }
}
```

I tried running the controller in main. but it didn't work. And I tried what I wrote above.

Comment: your case don't need to set an isLoading and use an Obx, just use the TabBar or TabBarView which will require the tabbarController directly, it will work fine since you initiate it in the onInit()

Comment: i change the func like this  -> loadController() async {
    
      tabController.value = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);

      update();
  }   and i change the widget like this  return TabBar(controller: tabbarController.tabController.value, tabs:const [
      Text("123",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      Text("123",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      Text("123",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      Text("123",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      Text("123",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
    ]);  but still not working